# Why does OMNet++ compiler gets errors for a precompiled package?

Tags: omnet++

I have included an external package callled SoPlex (a folder of `.cpp` and `.h` files and the library files) into my OMNet++ project. I have already tested the package in Code::Blocks IDE and it works fine besides some warnings it had: `warning: explicit conversion operators only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`.

It certainly was working in Code::Blocks IDE. But when I want to use it in my OMNet++ project it gives a lot of errors for the SoPlex package like in the picture: 
[image: Error messages]

It gives a lot of errors for just the code of SoPlex and not my OMNet++ project code.

Any idea what may cause the problem?

I have used MinGW to compile SoPlex package in Code::Blocks IDE. When I use `MinGW GCC` in OMNet++ instead of `GCC for OMNet++` as `current toolchain` there is this error `fatal error: omnetpp.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Could you provide a sample code which causes these errors as well as an error log from console? Probably a header file of your library is not correctly included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the errors with the 3rd party library. Depending where you put the library inside the src folder, at least that directory **must** be added as an include dir, otherwise the header files will not be found by the compiler.

As for the problem with the omnetpp.h: OMNeT++ has it's own makefile generator which automatically adds the required include folder (omnetpp_root/include). The generic MinGW GCC toolchain does not. If you want to avoid extra work, always use the omnet toolchain to build your models.